# What should I do to make the listview work in the fragment when I am getting data from the user and saving it into a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, android-sqlite

This shows one of the fragments that has the listview code in it which worked in it's own layout but does not work in the fragment. What should I do for this to work in the fragment? I am fairly new to android app development so I do not know what to do. if you do not understand what I am trying to do, I am having the user enter data into a form and then i want that data to be displayed in the fragment as a list so they can see all the data entered from beginning to end. I have been looking all over for a solution but i cannot find one that fits what i need to do. All the information i see is for pre-saved sq lite databases.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.attr.button;

public class tab3expense extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "tab3expense";
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private ListView mListView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3expense, container, false);
        return rootView;

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        populateListView();

    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

        //get the data and append to a list
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            //get the value from the database in column 1
            //then add it to the ArrayList
            listData.add(data.getString(1));
            listData.add(data.getString(2));
            listData.add(data.getString(3));
        }
        //create the list adapter and set the adapter
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);

                Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
                int itemID = -1;
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);
                }
                if(itemID > -1){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                    Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(tab3expense.this, add_expense.class);
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                    startActivity(editScreenIntent);
                }
                else{
                    toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the layout file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.dharquissandas.budget.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just for a clarification.. Tell me u r not getting any compilation errors after *return rootView;* line in *onCreateView*?

Comment: I am getting an error on this line: Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(tab3expense.this, add_expense.class);

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment class context will be accessed by in following method *getActivity()*. Here I make some change in your code. You have to inflate your layout view in *onCreateView()*, then cast your listview components in *onActivityCreated()*. Please get look on the following code. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Tab3expense extends Fragment {


    private static final String TAG = "tab3expense";
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private ListView mListView;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3expense, container, false);
        return rootView;



    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

        //get the data and append to a list
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            //get the value from the database in column 1
            //then add it to the ArrayList
            listData.add(data.getString(1));
            listData.add(data.getString(2));
            listData.add(data.getString(3));
        }
        //create the list adapter and set the adapter
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);

                Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
                int itemID = -1;
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);
                }
                if(itemID > -1){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                    Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), add_expense.class);
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                    startActivity(editScreenIntent);
                }
                else{
                    toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but it does not show any new data i add in from the form, it only shows old data. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @DeepHarquissandas you created the ArrayList with three data fixed size, try to change in dynamic ArrayList it will help to show new data.

Comment: how would I do that, I am fairly new at android programming and I am learning as a I go.

Answer (score -1):

Rearrange your code

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3expense, container, false);


        mListView = (ListView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

        populateListView();
 return rootView;

    }
```